# TypeError: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

Using `rullup`, I get an error when running the following command: `rollup -c --config rollup.config.js`.

Error:

```
[!] TypeError: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:163:11)
    at Object.resolve (node:path:1102:7)
    at getConfigPath (/Users/PROJECT_PATH/packages_node/packages/socket.io-controllers/node_modules/rollup/dist/bin/rollup:1593:22)
    at getConfigs (/Users/PROJECT_PATH/packages_node/packages/socket.io-controllers/node_modules/rollup/dist/bin/rollup:1683:34)
    at runRollup (/Users/PROJECT_PATH/packages_node/packages/socket.io-controllers/node_modules/rollup/dist/bin/rollup:1661:49)
    at Module.<anonymous> (/Users/PROJECT_PATH/packages_node/packages/socket.io-controllers/node_modules/rollup/dist/bin/rollup:1708:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
```

This is my configuration file:

```js
const dts = require("rollup-plugin-dts");
const esbuild = require("rollup-plugin-esbuild");
const name = require("./package.json").main.replace(/\.js$/, "");

const bundle = (config) => {
  return {
    ...config,
    input: "src/index.ts",
    external: (id) => !/^[./]/.test(id),
  };
};

export default [
  bundle({
    plugins: [esbuild()],
    output: [
      {
        file: `${name}.js`,
        format: "es",
      },
      {
        file: `${name}.mjs`,
        format: "cjs",
      },
    ],
  }),
  bundle({
    plugins: [dts()],
    output: {
      file: `${name}.d.ts`,
      format: "es",
    },
  }),
];
```

Dependencies versions:

```json
{
  ...
  "rollup": "^3.21.5",
  "rollup-plugin-dts": "^5.3.0",
  "rollup-plugin-esbuild": "^5.0.0",
  ...
}
```

I tried to use the `path` package but it didn't help:

```js
const path = require("path");
const dts = require("rollup-plugin-dts");
const esbuild = require("rollup-plugin-esbuild");
const name = require("./package.json").main.replace(/\.js$/, "");

const bundle = (config) => {
  return {
    ...config,
    input: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
    external: (id) => !/^[./]/.test(id),
  };
};

export default [
  bundle({
    plugins: [esbuild()],
    output: [
      {
        file: path.resolve(__dirname, `${name}.js`),
        format: "es",
      },
      {
        file: path.resolve(__dirname, `${name}.mjs`),
        format: "cjs",
      },
    ],
  }),
  bundle({
    plugins: [dts()],
    output: {
      file: path.resolve(__dirname, `${name}.d.ts`),
      format: "es",
    },
  }),
];
```